# 25MB file goes to page not found when uploading

Tags: php, performance, file-upload, upload

I have developed a script which uploads files to the website.

It works 100% for files around 2mb - 5mb but as soon as I hit the 25mb+ it starts uploading and gets to around 65% uploaded and then goes to a page not found screen even though its on a page which can be found.

At first I thought it could be the post limit or the max file size limit so I made them 256M and started again.

It did exactly the same, so I thought I would increase the `max_execution_time` and the `max_input_time` to 259200 and again it did the same, so I thought I would increase the `memory_limit` to 300M and that did not work either.

Just to recap, these are the settings I have changed and what I changed them too:

```
memory_limit: 300M
max_execution_time: 259200
max_input_time: 259200
post_max_size: 256M
upload_max_filesize: 256M
```

As you can see, uploading a 25mb file should not effect these.

I have made sure that the file permissions are set correctly also.

What else can it be?

Thanks :)

Comment: Which HTTP error code does it return?

Comment: @sanchises it does not give one :( its just a default chrome page saying This web page is not available

Comment: @sanchises the error report I have within the browser hidden divs are: Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED